# String constant versus variable

Tags: java

What's the difference between a string constant and a string variable?

Comment: Mutability?  Not sure what you are after.

Comment: by constant do you mean mutability or string literals?

Comment: with `string constant` did you mean `string literal`??

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for?

[Java - Variable, Constant and Literal in Java](http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/Varconstltr.shtml)

> **Variable :**
>
> You can assign the values to the
>   variable once it has been declared.
>   The values of the variable can be
>   changed anywhere in the program if the
>   variable is accessible in that scope.
>
> **Constants:**
>
> Constants are declared using the final
>   keyword. The values of the constant
>   can't be changed once its declared.

Answer (score 0):

In java a constant string means a String variable marked as final;

```
final String foo = "Some String";
```

And when a variable is marked as final it can not be changed throughout the program. And a String variable is simply

```
String bar = "Another String";
```

It can be changed as many times as you wish.
Note also that, whenever you assign a new string literal to a String variable, it does not changes the String, it creates a new one and then assigns it to the existing variable.